# When I build app for device its shows the following error in xcode.any kind of help is appreciated

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/Marigold/Documents/jaihnumantest3-19nov/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_Options_get", referenced from:

```
  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_Options_get_m1901254410 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _FirebaseApp_get_Options_m2698118079 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_FirebaseApp_Options_get_m1901254410)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ProjectId_get", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_get_ProjectId_m1800909474 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ProjectId_get_m2223006291 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ProjectId_get_m2223006291)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ProjectId_set", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_set_ProjectId_m86588109 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ProjectId_set_m737949489 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ProjectId_set_m737949489)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_StorageBucket_get", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_get_StorageBucket_m622229652 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_StorageBucket_get_m734571341 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_StorageBucket_get_m734571341)
```

"_Firebase_App_delete_AppOptions", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_Dispose_m3762685996 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_delete_AppOptions_m2952961198 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _Firebase_App_delete_AppOptionsInternal, _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_delete_AppOptions_m2952961198 )
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_StorageBucket_set", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_set_StorageBucket_m4105504921 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_StorageBucket_set_m1433941953 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_StorageBucket_set_m1433941953)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_MessageSenderId_get", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_get_MessageSenderId_m3578338096 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_MessageSenderId_get_m437239050 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_MessageSenderId_get_m437239050)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_MessageSenderId_set", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_set_MessageSenderId_m3787961582 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_MessageSenderId_set_m2571935390 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_MessageSenderId_set_m2571935390)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_GetDatabaseUrlInternal", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_GetDatabaseUrlInternal_m2258920037 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_GetDatabaseUrlInternal_m1529902189 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_GetDatabaseUrlInternal_m1529902189)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ApiKey_get", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_get_ApiKey_m1970997348 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ApiKey_get_m1262595438 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ApiKey_get_m1262595438)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ApiKey_set", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_set_ApiKey_m2694542877 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ApiKey_set_m273415714 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_ApiKey_set_m273415714)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_AppId_get", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_get_AppId_m991712355 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_AppId_get_m3638177201 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_AppId_get_m3638177201)
```

"_Firebase_App_new_AppOptions", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions__ctor_m3081644924 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_new_AppOptions_m2271694635 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _Firebase_App_new_AppOptionsInternal, _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_new_AppOptions_m2271694635 )
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_AppId_set", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_set_AppId_m2260494096 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_AppId_set_m2157330191 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_AppId_set_m2157330191)
```

"_Firebase_App_AppOptions_SetDatabaseUrlInternal", referenced from:

```
  _AppOptions_SetDatabaseUrlInternal_m3346983065 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

  _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_SetDatabaseUrlInternal_m1813312055 in Bulk_Firebase.App_0.o

 (maybe you meant: _AppUtilPINVOKE_Firebase_App_AppOptions_SetDatabaseUrlInternal_m1813312055)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: For all your pods set the setting "Build active architecture only" to NO.

Comment: it's not worked brother.Give me another solution, please.